# java.lang.SecurityException: android:sharedUserId

Tags: android

I am trying to share the db between 3 of my applications. There is some practical difficulty in using content provider at the moment and hence I use the android:sharedUserId such that I can share the db between 3 of my apps:

I get the following exception in my 3rd app and the logs are not getting printed when I tried to debug. I have cleaned the project, deleted APK and tried, still no luck. Following is the exception I get:

```
06-10 20:23:57.618: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 23% free 19751K/25543K, paused 36ms
06-10 20:23:57.618: I/ActivityManager(279): app/com.android.launcher[RESUMED] app.idle/true ...resumeTopActivityLocked
06-10 20:23:57.642: I/WindowManager(279): createSurface Window{41a45bb0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
06-10 20:23:57.657: D/dalvikvm(876): GC_CONCURRENT freed 499K, 25% free 31358K/41671K, paused 2ms+4ms
06-10 20:23:58.204: D/OpenGLRenderer(2729): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-10 20:23:58.728: D/OpenGLRenderer(2729): Flushing caches (mode 1)
06-10 20:23:58.728: I/ActivityManager(279): No longer want com.android.contacts (pid 2433): hidden #16
06-10 20:23:58.743: I/ActivityManager(279): removeActivityFromHistoryLocked, call sendFinishPackageName.
06-10 20:24:02.962: W/audio_hw_primary(136): select_output_device e=0, h=0, s=2, b=0
06-10 20:24:03.095: I/ActivityManager(279): app/com.example.dockbar[INITIAL] app.idle/false
06-10 20:24:03.095: I/ActivityManager(279): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.dockbar/.MainActivity} from pid 876
06-10 20:24:03.204: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 295K, 24% free 19549K/25543K, paused 60ms
06-10 20:24:03.204: I/WindowManager(279): createSurface Window{41b93940 Starting com.example.dockbar paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
06-10 20:24:03.212: I/ActivityManager(279): app/com.example.dockbar[RESUMED] app.idle/false ...realStartActivityLocked
06-10 20:24:03.235: W/System.err(2729): java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.nykkos.personalize (with uid 10096) to be run in process com.example.dockbar (with uid 10097)
06-10 20:24:03.235: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1584)
06-10 20:24:03.235: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1561)
06-10 20:24:03.235: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:1455)
06-10 20:24:03.235: W/System.err(2729):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:483)
06-10 20:24:03.243: W/System.err(2729):     at com.example.dockbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
06-10 20:24:03.243: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-10 20:24:03.243: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-10 20:24:03.243: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)
06-10 20:24:03.243: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1989)
06-10 20:24:03.243: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1149)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-10 20:24:03.251: W/System.err(2729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-10 20:24:03.259: W/System.err(2729):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 20:24:03.267: I/WindowManager(279): createSurface Window{41c59720 com.example.dockbar/com.example.dockbar.MainActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
06-10 20:24:03.360: D/OpenGLRenderer(876): Flushing caches (mode 1)
06-10 20:24:03.392: D/OpenGLRenderer(876): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-10 20:24:03.556: W/InputManagerService(279): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41fb7ee8 (uid=10050 pid=876)
06-10 20:24:03.931: I/ActivityManager(279): Displayed com.example.dockbar/.MainActivity: +723ms
06-10 20:24:12.681: D/shpowd(252): pcb_thermal_governor(40)
06-10 20:24:12.681: D/shpowd(252): pcb_thermal_governor(40) lock
06-10 20:24:12.681: D/shpowd(252): sh_check_limittemp(40) [53]   0 , 0
06-10 20:24:12.681: D/shpowd(252): sh_check_limittemp(40) [55]   0 , 0
06-10 20:24:12.681: D/shpowd(252): pcb_thermal_governor(40) unlock
```

I wonder why it works in one application and does not work in the other. The application does not get crashed due to this, but still I believe that, it is due to this exception that nothing happens in the activity class, except setting the layout. Following is my oncreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //code to make connectivty with shared db.
    Context sharedContext = null;
    try {
        // change package name if required
        sharedContext = this.createPackageContext("com.nykkos.personalize", Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
        if (sharedContext == null) {
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } 

    SQLiteDBHelper  dbHelper=new SQLiteDBHelper(sharedContext);
    try {
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Before db call in dockbar");

    appList=dbHelper.getList();
```

In the above code, layout is set, but the Systeem.out.println is not printed.

Can someone please guide me how to proceed resolving this issue

Comment: which one is line 45?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to share between debug and release builds?  I don't think that will work, as apps which wish to share a user ID must all be signed with the same certificate - so they'd all have to be release builds or all debug builds, all using the same release or debug certificate.  I wouldn't be surprised if there's a failure message produced in logcat when the apk is installed and it finds it doesn't qualify for sharedUserID (though you might have to remove it entirely to re-generate that)

Comment: I am building this as part of custom ROM. So, signing these apps with system signature would help?